# Customizing the ring chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am new to JFreeChart. I am creating a customized ring chart in JFreeChart. I did not get expected output.

```
private static JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset) {
    CustomRingPlot plot = new CustomRingPlot(dataset);

    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Custom Ring Chart", 
            JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, false);  

    plot.setBackgroundPaint(null);
    plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
    plot.setLabelGenerator(null);
    plot.setSectionPaint("A", Color.ORANGE);
    plot.setSectionPaint("B", new Color(100, 100, 100));
    plot.setSectionDepth(0.50);
    plot.setSectionOutlinesVisible(false);
    plot.setShadowPaint(null);
    plot.setSeparatorsVisible(false);
    plot.setExplodePercent("A", 0.05);
    plot.setExplodePercent("B", 0.05);
    plot.setAutoPopulateSectionOutlinePaint(true);
    plot.setSimpleLabels(true);

    return chart;
}
```

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

Actual output:

[image: actual output]

Comment: What output are you getting and what is expected?  Are there any logs etc.?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sid, I have edited the body part of my question and added the expected output & actual output as images.

Comment: It's not clear what difference you mean: data, color label? Please post a [mcve] and be specific about the problem.

Comment: Issue with data. Expected output image displaying both data but currently what i got actual output is displaying only one data.

Comment: What happens if you don't `null` the label generator?

Comment: Chart is proper, Chart is generated with actual data only, but value is not displaying  for second data. Our requirement is to display both the data.